# The equivalent of "./" in windows is ".exe" extension?

Tags: c, windows, gcc

I'm running in windows and I want to know what is the equivalent of **./my_program** in windows?
For example if I compile a file in c with gcc, something like

```
gcc my_program.c -o my_program
```

The I 've to launch it with `./my_progrm` in Linux,but in windows?

If I compile this : `gcc my_program.c -o my_program`, after I can't launch, I have to compile in that way : `gcc my_program.c -o my_program.exe`

I'm using minGW

Thank you

Comment: Just type `my_program` on command window after compilation/linking

Comment: Ok it works, without the "./"

Comment: Although if you preferred, `.\my_program` would work too. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./` is not an instruction to execute a program in Linux, but the path to the program to execute.
Actually, `./my_prog` means `I want to execute le 'my_prog' program in the current directory (.)`, but you can also do `../my_dir/my_prog` or anything else.

When you do `ls -l`, the shell understand `/bin/ls -l`.

In windows, if you are in the same directory as your .exe, you don't need to provide the path, just do `my_program.exe`

Actually, the `executables files` for Linux are binary files and they don't have any extension, but in windows it is `.exe`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!